# What is the difference between eth.contract and eth.Contract?

Tags: web3js

I don't get it. I've seeing two ways from tutorials on how to instantiate web3.

One is..

```
eth = new Eth(web3.currentProvider)
token = eth.contract(abi).at(contract_address);
```

and another is..

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
token = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
```

How are they different? And I can't find info on https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html with the small "c" for contract.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why. Small "c" is for web3 version below 1.0. Lowercase "c" and no "new". While big "C" is for version 1.0++.

Gosh, why they make like difficult for coders.

Comment: This is indeed the case. In web3 v0.x, use `web3.eth.contract`.

In web3 v1.x, use `new web3.eth.Contract`.

Comment: I have to add that usually class names are capitalized by convention, while it's attributes aren't, as you can see in `new Eth`, `new Web3` and `new web3.eth.Contract`.